# Promise {<pending>} being returned and await key word not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When running the below code and dumping out the `results` variable it returns `Promise {<pending>}`, I have added the await key word to the being of the function call so `const results = await getAllResults()` however this returns the error of `Unexpected reserved word 'await'`.

Anyone have any ideas?

```
useEffect(() => {

    async function getPageOfResults(page) {
        const response = await axios.get('https://swapi.dev/api/starships/?page=' + page);
        return response.data.results; 
    }

    async function getAllResults() {
        let starships = [];
        let lastResultsLength = 10;
        let page = 1;
        while (lastResultsLength === 10) {
            const newResults = await getPageOfResults(page);
            page++;
            lastResultsLength = newResults.length;
            starships = starships.concat(newResults);
        }

        return starships;
    }

    const results = getAllResults();

}, []);
```

Comment: Yes, `async` functions return Promises. That's how they work. What are you trying to do with the `results` variable? `starships` has the value you want, so why not just use that for whatever it is you want to do with `results`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `async` in the useEffect like so:

```
useEffect(async () => {

    async function getPageOfResults(page) {
        const response = await axios.get('https://swapi.dev/api/starships/?page=' + page);
        return response.data.results; 
    }

    async function getAllResults() {
        let starships = [];
        let lastResultsLength = 10;
        let page = 1;
        while (lastResultsLength === 10) {
            const newResults = await getPageOfResults(page);
            page++;
            lastResultsLength = newResults.length;
            starships = starships.concat(newResults);
        }

        return starships;
    }

    const results = await getAllResults();

}, []);
```

Comment: Oh yeah doh! Thanks.